# Loading classes from jars such that they end up with a certain name

Tags: java, class, jar

I'm working on a game project and for modding support my solution is to load a series of jar files from a folder; Each one has one class within with the same name as it - the "module class". I'm trying to load all of these module classes via a URLClassLoader such that their class names are things like "Modules.GenUtils.GenUtils". However, my current attempt results in a "ClassNotFoundException", like this one:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Modules.GenUtils.GenUtils
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at GameEngine.Configurables.ModuleManager.loadModule(ModuleManager.java:84)
    at GameEngine.Configurables.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:108)
    at Server.ServerExec.main(ServerExec.java:27)
```

Here's a picture of the file structure I'm talking about:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgHkF.png)

And here's the code that loads each module:

```
    private static void loadModule(String moduleName) throws Exception
    {
        Logging.logNotice("Loading module " + moduleName + ".");
    
        URL url = new URL("jar", "", "file:" + GameInfo.getServerPackResource("Modules/" + moduleName + ".jar"));
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {url});
        Class moduleClass = classLoader.loadClass("Modules." + moduleName + "." + moduleName);
    
        Module module = (Module) moduleClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

        modules.put(moduleName, module);
        modulePriorities.add(moduleName);
    
        Logging.logNotice("Loaded module " + moduleName + ".");
        module.initModule();
    }
```

Comment: HI @Iacon1 - your example has `Modules.GenUtils.GenUtils` but the exception is missing the second dot - is that expected??

Comment: Thanks, that was _an_ error. Unfortunately correcting that did not resolve the issue nor change the error received in a meaningful way. Still, I edited the question to reflect that correction.